# Do souls inter-communicate among themselves after death?

Tags: death, soul

Do souls of dead Muslims who knew each other during their lifetimes communicate with each other after death? If so, can the soul of the person that died later communicate news of the ones left behind (still alive)? I am quite keen to know answers to these questions based on the Qur'an and the authentic Ahadeeth, and as understood by the Salaf-us-Saliheen. Jazakallahu khairan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yes](http://sunnah.com/nasai/21/16), the souls of Muslims can meet and communicate after death, [Source](http://islamqa.info/ar/ref/20820).  The Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) [said](http://sunnah.com/nasai/21/16):

> فَيَأْتُونَ بِهِ أَرْوَاحَ الْمُؤْمِنِينَ فَلَهُمْ أَشَدُّ فَرَحًا
>   بِهِ مِنْ أَحَدِكُمْ بِغَائِبِهِ يَقْدَمُ عَلَيْهِ فَيَسْأَلُونَهُ
>   مَاذَا فَعَلَ فُلاَنٌ مَاذَا فَعَلَ فُلاَنٌ فَيَقُولُونَ دَعُوهُ
>   فَإِنَّهُ كَانَ فِي غَمِّ الدُّنْيَا
>
> Then the souls of the believers come to him and they rejoice more over
>   him than any one of you rejoices when his absent loved one comes to
>   him. They ask him: 'What happened to so-and-so, what happened to
>   so-and-so?' They say: 'Let him be, for he was in the hardship of the
>   world

And Allah knows best, may he forgive my mistakes.

Comment: How does you deduce from the reference that souls communicate with one another?

Comment: @goto I edited my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: And it's *barzakh* where they meet. Right?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Ibn AlQayyim mentioned this in his book while retelling the story that led to this ayah being revealed in the first place.

The Prophet's companions worried they would be cut off from him when he dies, so they never wanted to leave him during his life, so God revealed that to prove to them that as long as one does good deeds

And whoso obeys Allah and the Messenger (Muhammad SAW), then they will be in the company of those on whom Allah has bestowed His Grace, of the Prophets, the Siddiqun (those followers of the Prophets who were first and foremost to believe in them, like Abu Bakr As-Siddiq radhiallahu'anhu), the martyrs, and the righteous. And how excellent these companions are!

Comment: It would be nice to quote the title of ibn al-Qyyims book, he has written a whole lot, so saying in his book is more than vague!

Comment: And which ayah is "this" ?